# React event triggers multiple times

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I am currently working on a small app which uses React and Leaflet and its purpose is to find the best route with all the markers that the user has added to the map.

The code works fine, but my problem is that once I click the button to start the routing, each time I click it again it "stacks" in the background.
To be more specific, it runs multiple times(onClick event) with old markers in the background, to the point that the app crashes.

I've tried many different approaches to fix this, but none have worked so far.

**App.js(Main Code)**

```
import React, {createRef, Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import L, { Point } from 'leaflet';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup,LayerGroup } from 'react-leaflet';
import icon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import Routing from "./routingMachine";
import Control from 'react-leaflet-control';

let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: icon,
    iconAnchor: [10, 55],
});

L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;


export default class App extends Component  {

  constructor() {
    super();

        this.state = {
        isMapInit: false,
        hasLocation: false,
        flag: true,
        latlng: {
          lat: 31.0461,
          lng: 34.8516,
        },
        markers:[],
        rMarkers:[],
      };

    this.routingEvent = this.routingEvent.bind(this);
  }


  saveMap = map => {

      this.map = map;
      this.setState({
        isMapInit: true
      });
  
    };

  mapRef = createRef<Map>()

  addMarker = (e) => {
    const {markers,flag} = this.state
    if(flag){
      markers.push(e.latlng)
      this.setState({markers})
    }

  }

  routingEvent = event =>{
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(event);
    const {rMarkers,markers,flag} = this.state
    let rMarkers2 = markers.slice()
    const map = this.map
    
    let pointer = this
    let myLocation=null
    if(map!=null && flag == true)
    {
        myLocation = map.leafletElement.locate({setView:false,maxZoom:16}).on('locationfound',function(e){
          rMarkers2.unshift(e.latlng)
          if(rMarkers2.length>=2){
            console.log("newMarkers")
            console.log(rMarkers2)
            console.log(pointer.map.leafletElement)
            pointer.btnReview.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            pointer.setState((state,props) => ({rMarkers:rMarkers2,markers:[],flag:false}))

          }
          else{
            console.log("not enough points");
          }
      });
    }
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    const { lat, lng } = event.latlng
    this.addMarker(event)
    
  }

  updateRoute = () =>{
    this.setState((state,props) =>({markers:[],rMarkers:[],flag:true}))
    this.btnReview.removeAttribute("disabled")
  }
  


  render(){
    const marker = this.state.hasLocation ? (
      <Marker position={this.state.latlng}>
        <Popup>You are here</Popup>
      </Marker>
    ) : null


    return (

      <Map className="map" onClick={this.handleClick}  ref= {this.saveMap}
        onLocationfound={this.handleLocationFound}
      center={this.state.latlng} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <LayerGroup>
            {this.state.markers.map((position, idx) => 
              <Marker key={`marker-${idx}`} position={position}>
                <Popup>
                  <span>Popup</span>
                </Popup>
              </Marker>
            )}
        </LayerGroup>
        <Control position="topleft" >
          <button 
            onClick={  
              this.updateRoute
              
              }
          >
            Reset Markers
          </button>
        </Control>
        <Control position="topleft" >
          <button onClick={this.routingEvent} ref={btnReview  => {this.btnReview = btnReview;}} >
            Plan route
          </button>
          
        </Control>

        <Routing mapInit = {this.state.isMapInit}  id="routeI" name="routeM" map={this.map} pointM={this.state.rMarkers} routingFlag = {this.state.flag} /> 

      </Map>
  
    );
  }
}
```

**routingMachine.js**

```
import { MapLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
import { withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import React from 'react';
class Routing extends MapLayer {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  createLeafletElement() {
    console.log("ele-leaf create");
    const { map ,pointM} = this.props;

    console.log(pointM);
    console.log(this.props.pointM);

    let leafletElement = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: this.props.pointM
    }).addTo(map.leafletElement);


  this.routing = leafletElement;


    return leafletElement.getPlan();
  }
  updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps) {
      console.log('leafletUPDATE')
      console.log(fromProps)
      console.log(toProps)

    if(fromProps.pointM != toProps.pointM && (toProps.routingFlag == false)){
        const { map ,pointM,routing} = toProps;

    function generatePermutations(Arr){
        var permutations = [];
        var A = Arr.slice();
      
        function swap(a,b){
          var tmp = A[a];
          A[a] = A[b];
          A[b] = tmp;
        }
      
        function generate(n, A){
          if (n == 1){
            permutations.push(A.slice());
          } else {
            for(var i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
              generate(n-1, A);
              swap(n % 2 == 0 ? i : 0 ,n-1);
            }
          }
        }
        
        generate(A.length, A);
        return permutations;
    }

      var Points =[];
      toProps.pointM.forEach(e=>{

        Points.push([e.lat,e.lng]);
      });

      var x = generatePermutations(Points);
      var l = [];
      if(x.length <2){
        console.log("no dist");
        console.log(this.routing);
        this.routing.setWaypoints([]);   
      }
      else{
          var myLocation = [toProps.pointM[0].lat,toProps.pointM[0].lng]
          const Undef = 1000000;
          x.forEach(e=>{
            if(e[0][0] == myLocation[0] && e[0][1] == myLocation[1])
            {
              var sum=0;
              for(var i=0; i < e.length-1 ; i++){
                sum+=distance(e[i][0], e[i][1], e[i+1][0], e[i+1][1], 'K');
              }
              l.push(sum);
            }else{
              l.push(Undef)
            }
          });

          var route = l.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null,l));

          this.routing.setWaypoints(x[route]);
          console.log(x[route]);
  
        
      }

      function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
        var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
        var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
        var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
        var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
        var theta = lon1-lon2
        var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
        var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        dist = Math.acos(dist)
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
        if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344 }
        if (unit=="N") { dist = dist * 0.8684 }
        return dist
      }

    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount()
    console.log("update")
  }

}
export default withLeaflet(Routing);
```

How can I keep this event from triggering using data from older states?

Comment: Please provide the complete code with render method.

Comment: Ok, just updated it. thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you add the listener multiple times: `.on('locationfound',function(e){` I don't know if this fix this but try to use the listener only one time or clear it like: `.off().on('locationfound',function(e){`

Comment: Thank @FalkeDesign worked like a charm , you're my unsung hero ! cant belive i missed this. but off() didnt worked perfectly for me so i just used once() which did .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answerd in the comments:

The Problem was that the listener was added multiple times, fixed with `.once()` instead of `on()`.